# Padding in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, padding

I want to use padding for the last 4 number of my zip code.

EX. if my zip is `12345999` then I want to replace `9999` with `6789`.

If there is not `9999` at the last four positions, then no need to replace.

Comment: You should really make some effort and try searching for an answer on the internet first. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

You could use replace

```
 SELECT REPLACE(your_column, '9999', '6789')
 from your_table
 where RIGHT(your_column,4) ='9999';
```

or for update

```
 Update your_table
 set your_column =  REPLACE(your_column, '9999', '6789')
 where RIGHT(your_column,4) ='9999';
```